# if statement on validate File Upload, but error is still showing?

Tags: php, image, forms, validation, file-upload

I have a PHP validate statement for a file upload on a HTML form. It has errors that are printed if the file is not an image or if the file extension isn't supported. The `if` statement states that if `$_FILES` is empty to validate it, and show up the appropriate errors. The problem is that although the file upload is not a required input, the error message "file does not seem to be an image" shows up even if the `$_FILES` variable is empty? Can someone please help

```
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

if($_FILES != "") // [START FILE UPLOADED]
{
    include 'image_validate.php';

    $file = $_FILES['eventPhoto'];

    $file_name = $file['name'];

    $error = ''; // Empty

    // Get File Extension (if any)
    $ext = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file_name, "."), 1));

    // Check for a correct extension. The image file hasn't an extension? Add one
    if($validation_type == 1)
    {
        $file_info = getimagesize($_FILES['eventPhoto']['tmp_name']);

        if(empty($file_info)) // No Image?
        {
            $error .= "<br/><div class='submitEventErrors'>The uploaded file doesn't seem to be an image.</div><br/>";
        }
        else // An Image?
        {
            $file_mime = $file_info['mime'];

            if($ext == 'jpc' || $ext == 'jpx' || $ext == 'jb2')
            {
                $extension = $ext;
            }
            else
            {
                $extension = ($mime[$file_mime] == 'jpeg') ? 'jpg' : $mime[$file_mime];
            }

            if(!$extension)
            {
                $extension = '';
                $file_name = str_replace('.', '', $file_name);
            }
        }
    }

    else if($validation_type == 2)
    {
        if(!in_array($ext, $image_extensions_allowed))
        {
            $exts = implode(', ',$image_extensions_allowed);
            $error .= "<br/><div class='submitEventErrors'>You must upload a file with one of the following extensions: ".$exts."</div>";
        }

        $extension = $ext;
    }

    if($error)
    {
        echo '<font color="red">'.$error.'</font>';
    }

    if($error == "") // No errors were found?
    {
        $new_file_name = strtolower($file_name);
        $new_file_name = str_replace(' ', '-', $new_file_name);
        $new_file_name = substr($new_file_name, 0, -strlen($ext));
        $new_file_name .= $extension;

    }
    else
    {
        @unlink($file['tmp_name']);
    }

} // [END FILE UPLOADED]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using is_uploaded_file instead of 
if($_FILES != "")

More details here 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php